# How do you write a program that uses different classes to handle user input and output?

Tags: java, class, input, output

I am new to OOP and having enormous difficulty in grasping the OOP-ness of the language. I come from a fairly firm background in 'C' programming, and the logic and execution of its tasks seem very reasonable and intuitive. With OOP it is very difficult for a noob such as myself to see the advantages of classes and utilizing them. In short, I desire to write a program: a very SIMPLE program to illustrate the interplay between two classes: one 'mother' class to call on a class that allows user input to occur by instantiating an object of the 'getInput' class, and then call on the object in the 'mother' class to print out that input. Below is the pseudocode that I attempted to use to achieve this, which has failed:

```
public class mother {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        GetUserInput userInput = new GetUserInput();  //Here I create an object in GetUser input class that I want to reference in the mother class to get output
        System.out.println(input);

    }                       
} 


import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetUserInput {
     public String input;

     Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
     input = userInput.next();

}
```

I just don't see why this code type will fail? I instantiated an object in the mother class. Then I instantiated an object of the scanner class that would allow user input. I do not see why this code is not working.

Comment: Code should be inside a `method`. In `GetUserInput` it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you can't have statements such as `input = userInput.next()` just floating in the class body like that.

Secondly, you create a new `GetUserInput` class and then never do anything on it.

The idea of OOP is that your classes model concepts in your domain. It's difficult to give specific advice without a better idea of what you're trying to do here. However, a brief example is given below:

```
public class Mother {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GetInput inputReader = new GetInput();
    String input = inputReader.read();
    System.out.println(input);
  }

public class GetInput {
  public String read() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    return scanner.next();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Tom G. Basically, I want to see a simple bit of code that consists of two classes: my 'main' or 'mother' class that will instantiate an object of a 'GetUserInput' class. I want this 'GetUserInput' class to scan input from a user. I then want the 'mother' class to reference that object to print the user's input FROM the mother class. A simple program, useless, but able to demonstrate the syntax and semantics of using calling on objects. I'm using 2 Java books, watching every tutorial that Youtube has, but I cannot yet fluently utilize the interplay between classes.

Answer (score 1):

Think of an OOP class as a combination of a struct (fields) with the functions (methods) that operate on or with it. (This is literally how classes work in C++.) The lines written inside the class body (like variable declarations) are essentially a struct initializer, in combination with the class's constructor(s); these lines actually get copied into the constructor methods by the compiler.

It doesn't make sense to put all sorts of random code inside an initializer, and Java, mostly the only code you can put in the class body itself is variable declarations and initializations.

In this specific case, your `GetUserInput` class doesn't make much sense; as a struct, it would only have a single string component, and you don't have any interesting functions that go along with it. Just use the `String` instead. If you do have interesting processing to do, declare the fields that you'd have in your struct (`int quantity, price;` or whatever), and write a constructor that takes a `Scanner` as an input and sets those values to something useful.

(As a note, classes are generally like nouns, and the methods on them are generally like verbs, and the naming conventions reflect this. `UserInput` would be clearer.)

Based on what you're talking about, here's some pseudocode for the main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        UserInput input = new UserInput(inputScanner);
        System.out.println(input.getInput());
    }
}
```